# Window is good for the first time, spoiled for the second time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm making a WPF application which has a Menu and has a GameBoard. One command of the Menu closes the Menu and creates a GameBoard. The code of the command:

```
            GameBoardViewModel _viewModel = new GameBoardViewModel();
            _viewModel.setupGame(PlayerStartups.Where(p => p.Status != Status.Closed).ToList());

            GameBoardWindow _window = new GameBoardWindow();
            _viewModel.EndGameEvent += (s, e) =>
            {
                _window.Close();
            };
            ((StartMenuWindow)param).Close();
            _window.DataContext = _viewModel;
            _window.setEventHandlers();
            _window.Show();
```

After the game is over, the GameBoard opens a new Menu like this:

```
        this.EndGameEvent += (s, e) =>
        {
            StartMenuWindow smw = new StartMenuWindow();
            smw.DataContext = new StartMenuViewModel();
            smw.Show();
        };
```

My problem is the following: for the first time the GameBoard shows just fine, the game is playable. But when i try to create another game (from the Menu opened from the previous game), the characters won't get drawn. The source of their images are set just like the first time, but they just won't appear. Also I can do everything (every command runs), only there is no response. For example when I invoke the command which is responsible for rolling the dices (thus moving the characters), the position of the characters are changed like it should be, only nothing happens.

Comment: Are you using the same instance of _window? If you close it and then try to Show it you might have issues.

Comment: nope, a totally new window.

Comment: *"The source of their images are set just like the first time"* - how exactly are they set? Check for binding errors in Output window when you run second `GameBoard`, it seems you don't deal properly with `DataContext` or ViewModel.

Comment: @Sinatr they are set from a database while initializing the characters. why would you say that i don't deal properly with `DataContext` or ViewModel?

Comment: I'm curious what we might learn if you inspect the visual tree.  Start up the first game, and then use WPF Snoop from Codeplex or the VS2015 Visual Tree Inspector to find some properly set values on these image objects.  Next, start up the second game, and delve into the visual tree again to see if the values differ.

Comment: Thanks, by doing that I saw that some static fields caused the problem. If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it :)